# Resetting default launcher to system factory default

Tags: android

I ran into the following issue: I have an app I want my user to be able to select it as the launcher app. So far, no issues there.
Clearing said selection programmatically also isnt an issue here. Where my issue occurs is the following:
When I my custom launcher programmatically I want to go back to default launcher app, e.g. the default on a samsung galaxy. clearing the launch settings over clearPackagePrefferedActivities clears all of it but once i press the home button I get the dialog to select a default launcher again.
Is there anyway to revert back programmatically to the default launcher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user always needs to confirm a change in the default settings. You can always trigger the "default launcher" dialog by

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
ComponentName cm = new ComponentName(this, FakeLauncherActivity.class);
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(cm, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

Intent homeIntent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(homeIntent);

pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(cm, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Where FakeLauncherActivity is just another Activity in your app with the intent-filter HOME/MAIN/DEFAULT (without LAUNCHER).

If you want to know the default system launcher you could query the intents answering the LAUNCHER Intent, but if the user has another Launcher installed, you will not know which one is the default system launcher.

Even if this is not a complete solution for your question, I hope it helps you in a useful direction.

Comment: Ahh, shame. Exactly what I thought. To get around the fact which launcher was previously selected (and treating that one as the one to revert to) I query that one before. Sadly you cant set a package as a default launcher anymore, if a am not mistaken?

Comment: No you can't - unfortunately (or for users safety)

Comment: I was just curious as apps like fully kiosk mode trigger the first dialogue like i do and upon leaving the "kiosk mode" give you the simple option to reset the launcher to the previous default one.

Comment: I do not know this app, but maybe they do exactly this, check which app answers before and trigger the dialogue after. I am not aware of any other possibility.

Comment: Upon a bit closer inspection: Is it possible to add the default intent to an activity and use that one as default launcher? I tried that one and set the default intent + the activity to disabled and only activated it when I was triggering the launch selector (actually similar to the fakelauncher). however, selecting the always option isnt persistent here.

Comment: To be more precisly: when including the activity here that isnt the main activity everytime the home button gets tapped the selection dialogue is triggered

Comment: I think this is because the LAUNCHER Intent is only temporary and not in the manifest.